# The return type 'Database' isn't a 'Future<void>',

Tags: dart, sqflite

Hello I am getting this error
I want to **return** the database object for the function **database**

I am getting this error **The return type 'Database' isn't a 'Future < void >'**

dart

```
Future < Database > database() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join( await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)");
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE todo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, taskId INTEGER, title TEXT, status INTEGER)");
        return db ;
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }
```

Here is my code
I want to access that database function for my future function

**Here is my Sample Next function**

```
Future<int> insertTask(Task task) async {
    int taskId = 0;
    Database _db = await database();
    await _db.insert('tasks', task.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace).then((value) {
      taskId = value;
    });
    return taskId;
  }
```

**Another Function**

```
Future<void> insertTodo(Todo todo) async {
  Database _db = await database();
  await _db.insert('todo', todo.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}
```

`Print("Hi")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Future <Database> database() async {
    return await openDatabase(
      join( await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)");
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE todo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, taskId INTEGER, title TEXT, status INTEGER)");
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have already tried this.

Comment: Hello @ZAEEMASGHAR, did you notice the `await`?

Comment: yes i have already tried your code

Comment: And you still got the same error?

Comment: yes same answer as mentioned

Comment: I made edit, please check it...I `return db`

Comment: Hey, @ZAEEMASGHAR, does it work now?